# Why I am receiving a runtime error in Codechef?

Tags: python

I am getting runtime error(NZEC) on Codechef. Can anyone tell me why?

```
withdrwal = int(input())
balance = float(input())
amt = balance - withdrwal- 0.5
if (withdrwal%5!=0 or withdrwal+0.5>balance):
    print('%.2f'%balance)
else:
    print('%.2f'%amt)
```

Comment: The code works for me when I run it

Comment: It works perfectly in local compiler, but gets an error on Codechef. So, I got the solution by mapping the input and splitting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you're trying to read input when there is no more input left to read and python raises an exception, the online judge in return gives the (NZEC) error. Try using raw_input() instead of input(). Comment back to let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks man! Got the solution by mapping the input and splitting them. withdrwal,balance=map(float,input().split())

Comment: That's a better approach for handling inputs in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

It's because for the specific sum that you are solving, the inputs are probably given in the same line. ie.

```
20  50
```

Your code expects inputs one after the other:

```
20
50
```

Try changing the input format in your code something like this:

```
withdrawal, balance = map(float, input().split())
```